# Does Off-The-Record protocol provide future (backward) secrecy?

Tags: protocol-design, forward-secrecy, future-secrecy

I know Signal provides future (backward) secrecy, and that it is based on Off-The-Record protocol. However, does OTR by itself also provide future secrecy?

Answer (score 1):

I think so. OTR generates a new DH key pair for each round of message, similar to the DH ratchet in Signal. Also, OTR stands out by having a property called [deniable authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_authentication). This basically means the messages are only authenticated during a session between the communicating parties but not after the session. In fact, the MAC key will be revealed after the session is closed.

Comment: Does Signal not provide deniability?

Comment: @Kek Signal provides cryptographic deniability. But WhatsApp group messaging doesn't.